# How do I download a file from Azure Blob Storage to a .NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking for the simplest way to download a file from Azure Blob Storage container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique should work for any .NET Core application.

Add the following Nuget packages:

1. [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity)
2. [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs)

Add a file to your project called BlobService.cs and paste the contents of this [file](https://github.com/slemrick77/Emrick-BlobService-Lite/blob/master/BlobService.cs).

Next, instantiate and authenticate to your container. In this example, I am using the Connection String method. I have logged into the Azure Portal, and copied the connection string from the Access Keys page of the Storage Account.  Click https://github.com/slemrick77/Emrick-BlobService-Lite#authenticate-using-a-connection-string for more information about Access Keys.

**Note:**  For production scenarios, you will want to register your application and use a client id/secret to authenticate.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication-on-premises-apps?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Ccommand-line for details.

```
string BlobConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=StevesStorageAccount;AccountKey=REDACTED==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

Emrick.CStringBlobService blobService = 
    new Emrick.CStringBlobService(BlobConnectionString, "file-uploads");
```

Note that the constructor takes both the connection string AND the name of the container.

Next, we simply call the GetContentsOfFolder method. This method returns a List of file names in the specified folder path.

```
List<string> listOfFiles = 
    blobService.GetContentsOfFolder(filePath);
```

In order to download a file, call the GetFile method.  This will return a stream of the file contents.

```
System.IO.Stream fileData = blobService.GetFile("2023 Resume.pdf");
```

Once you have the file in a stream, you can save it locally or display it to your user.  For example, to save locally, simply:

```
using (System.IO.Stream file = File.Create("C:\\2023 Resume.pdf"))
{
    fileData.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you need an additional service that provides an abstraction over the blob storage SDK. Also, to not recommend using a managed identity seems like a missed point to me.